# check if it is clicked or not jquery

Tags: jquery, click

i have an multiple select on my page and i want to check if it is clicked or not. i use this code:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

            var hasBeenClicked = false;
            jQuery('#form_products').click(function () {
                hasBeenClicked = true;
            });

            if (!hasBeenClicked==true) {
                alert("clicked");
            } else {
                alert("not clicked");
            }

        });
```

when i click it alerts "clicked" but when i dont click it doesnt alert anything. how to fix that? thank you..

Comment: By 'clicked' do you mean to test whether an option was selected?

Answer (score 0):

you are binding the click event inside the submit callback function, becouse of that, when you click on #form_products, the click event will never be called.

try put your click bind on document.ready event like this.

```
$(function () {
    var hasBeenClicked = false;

    $('#form_products').click(function () {
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    });

    $("form").submit(function(){
        if (hasBeenClicked) {
            alert("clicked");
        } else {
            alert("not clicked");
        }

    });
});
```